# Solution regarding Power Series and ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

About 4 months ago I posted [Series solution to $y''-xy'-y=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584645/series-solution-to-y-xy-y-0/731925?noredirect=1#731925).  I ran through the analysis and it appeared that I solved the ODE .  The solution seemed to be
$$y=a_0+\frac{a_1}{1}x+\frac{a_0}{2}x^2+\frac{a_1}{1 \cdot 3}x^3+\frac{a_0}{2 \cdot 4}x^4+\frac{a_1}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5}+...$$
$$=a_0\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{2^kk!}+a_1\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^kk!x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$
It appears that my summation is wrong and, at least, the $a_0$ term should be
$$\frac{a_0}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{k!}$$
since my $a_0$ terms are
$$\frac{a_0x^{2\cdot 0}}{2(1)},\frac{a_0x^{2\cdot 1}}{2(1)},\frac{a_0x^{2\cdot 2}}{2(2\cdot 1)},\frac{a_0x^{2\cdot 3}}{2(3\cdot 2\cdot 1)},\frac{a_0x^{2\cdot 4}}{2(4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1)},...$$
Thus, one possible solution seems to be $y=\frac{e^{x^2}}{2}$, since
$$e^{x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x^2)^k}{k!}.$$  But when I differentiate $y$ twice and plug the derivitives and original equation in the ODE, I get
$$y''-xy'-y=0$$
$$2x^2e^{x^2}+e^{x^2}-x^2e^{x^2}-\frac{e^{x^2}}{2}\neq 0$$
So.....thoughts?  Why am I not calculating right?  Am I just missing something simple?

Comment: You misunderstood the remarks to your other question. The even parts of the solutions are indeed multiples of $x\mapsto\exp(x^2/2)$. To sum up: "It appears that my summation is wrong" It is not, check again.

Comment: $e^{x^2}$ is not a solution to the ODE. Your previous solution $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ was correct. Something is wrong with your series.