# Show the given series is a solution of $y''-xy'-y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

My problem is this:
"Show that the function represented by the power series, $$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{2^nn!}=1+ \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^4}{8}+ \frac{x^6}{48}+...$$ is a solution of the differential equation, $y''-xy'-y=0$."

This older question ([Series solution to $y''-xy'-y=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584645/series-solution-to-y-xy-y-0)) looks at this same differential equation but from a slightly different perspective.  I'm unable to use that posting's information to solve my problem.

I'm either making a simple mistake, or I have a novice misunderstanding causing a flawed approach. I've gotten the following:  $$y'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n \cdot x^{2n-1}}{2^nn!}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n-1}}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}= x+ \frac{x^3}{2}+ \frac{x^5}{8}+...= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2^nn!}$$

and

$$y''=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n-1) \cdot x^{2n-2}}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}= 1+ \frac{3x^2}{2}+ \frac{5x^4}{8}+ \frac{7x^6}{48}+...= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n+1) \cdot x^{2n}}{2^nn!}$$
If I substitute the individual summation terms in the differential equation, it's clear that the answer equals zero:
$$y''-xy'-y=0$$
$$(1+ \frac{3x^2}{2}+ \frac{5x^4}{8}+ \frac{7x^6}{48}+...)-x(x+ \frac{x^3}{2}+ \frac{x^5}{8}+...)-(1+ \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^4}{8}+ \frac{x^6}{48}+...)=0$$ 
But I'm wondering and hoping I could show that with the sigma notation. I use the sigmas indexed from 0 (and also multiply the $y'$ expression by $x$ to fit the differential equation): 
$$y''-xy'-y=0$$
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n+1) \cdot x^{2n}}{2^nn!} -x \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2^nn!}\right) -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{2^nn!}$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{(2n+1) \cdot x^{2n}}{2^nn!} - x \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2^nn!} - \frac{x^{2n}}{2^nn!}\right)=0$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{(2n+1) \cdot x^{2n}-x^{2n+2}-x^{2n}}{2^nn!}\right)=0$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2n \cdot x^{2n}-x^{2n+2}}{2^nn!}\right)=0$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{(2n-x^2)}{2^nn!}x^{2n}\right)=0$$

But that's useless.  I want some expression on the left which has to equal zero.   I don't see how to show that.

Is there some other way to do this?  I've spent so much time on this problem and reworked it so many times I can hardly see straight, and I can't see a problem with the index shifting or some other flaw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to compare the terms in front of x of the same power.

So rewrite the sum with $x^{2n+2}$ term to a $x^{2n}$ (just shift all the n's in the sum by one. You can do that because different sums are independent of each other.) and then compare.

Comment: I'm trying... just need some time to work through it...

Answer (score 2):

You wrote $y'=...=x+x^3/2+x^5/8+...=-1+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2 n+1}/2^n n!$ which is a mistake because the "$-1$" should be erased. With that correction,there is no "$x$" term in your last line and the summation is $0$ because it is a telescoping series of the form $(a_0-a_1)+(a_1-a_2)+(a_2-a_3)+....$ with $a_0=0$ and with $a_n$ converging to $0$. You can avoid the telescope by writing $x y'$ as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{2 n}/2^{n-1}(n-1)!$ and taking the constant terms contributed  by $y''$ and $y$ outside of the infinite summation, and summing from $n=1$ to $\infty .$ Then the coefficients are all $0$.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, I've edited out that error and am working to fix the answer.

Answer (score 2):

By inspection, $y=\exp\tfrac{x^2}{2}$ so $$y'=xy,\,y''=\left(1+x^2\right)y,\,y''-xy'-y=y\left(1+x^2-x\cdot x-1\right)=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Aha! Thanks to Piotr's tip (and the now-corrected summation error in the $y'$ expression), if I take the second-to-last equation
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2n \cdot x^{2n}-x^{2n+2}}{2^nn!}\right)=0$$ I can rewrite it as
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2nx^{2n}}{2^nn!}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+2}}{2^nn!} =0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2nx^{2n}}{2^nn!}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!} =0 \quad(*)$$
The first sum in this last equation can be written as $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2nx^{2n}}{2^nn!}=0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2nx^{2n}}{2^nn!}$$
I can then combine the summations from equation (*) again, since they're both now indexed to start at 1:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2nx^{2n}}{2^nn!}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!} =0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2nx^{2n}-2nx^{2n}}{2^nn!}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n-2n}{2^nn!}x^{2n}=0$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 0\cdot x^{2n}=0$$